# Android ValueAnimator animation not working an API 19

Tags: android, android-animation, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm testing my application on an OUSHENG x8 mini pro, API 19 (4.4.2).

In particular the issue I'm facing is in the behavior of a ProgressBar animated with a couple of ValueAnimator objects:

```
private AnimatorSet animatorSet;
private ValueAnimator R2LAnimation;
private ValueAnimator L2RAnimation;
public ValueAnimator getL2RAnimation(final ProgressBar progressBar) {
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, progressBar.getMax());
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            LogUtils.traceD(LOG_TAG, "Animation Progress Value: " + value);
            progressBar.setProgress(value);
        }
    });
    return valueAnimator;
}

public ValueAnimator getR2LAnimation(final ProgressBar progressBar) {
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(progressBar.getMax(), 0);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            LogUtils.traceD(LOG_TAG, "Animation Progress Value: " + value);
            progressBar.setProgress(value);
        }
    });
    return valueAnimator;
}
```

This is my log output:

```
09-17 17:27:00.408 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>:  Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 17:27:00.408 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1000
09-17 17:27:00.409 24923-25478/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7ca17488 sslRead buf=0x42b3a8a0 len=8192,timeo=15000
09-17 17:27:00.411 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.413 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw View @42138848 paint 0x82af3e08 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0x1f000000
09-17 17:27:00.414 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.422 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1000
09-17 17:27:00.422 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>:  Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 17:27:00.425 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.426 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw View @42138848 paint 0x82af3e08 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0x1f000000
09-17 17:27:00.426 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.431 24923-26483/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/FA: Connected to remote service
09-17 17:27:00.435 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>:  Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 17:27:00.435 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1000
09-17 17:27:00.438 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.440 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw View @42138848 paint 0x82af3e08 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0x1f000000
09-17 17:27:00.440 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.446 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1000
09-17 17:27:00.447 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>:  Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 17:27:00.453 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.454 24923-26483/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/SQLiteDatabase: beginTransaction()
09-17 17:27:00.456 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw View @42138848 paint 0x82af3e08 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0x1f000000
09-17 17:27:00.457 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.464 24923-26483/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
09-17 17:27:00.464 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>:  Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 17:27:00.466 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1000
09-17 17:27:00.470 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.472 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw View @42138848 paint 0x82af3e08 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0x1f000000
09-17 17:27:00.473 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.482 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1000
09-17 17:27:00.483 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>:  Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 17:27:00.491 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.494 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw View @42138848 paint 0x82af3e08 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0x1f000000
09-17 17:27:00.496 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.502 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>:  Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 17:27:00.502 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1000
09-17 17:27:00.510 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.514 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw View @42138848 paint 0x82af3e08 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0x1f000000
09-17 17:27:00.525 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.573 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1000
09-17 17:27:00.573 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>:  Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 17:27:00.616 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.621 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw View @42138848 paint 0x82af3e08 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0x1f000000
09-17 17:27:00.622 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x80659aa0>
09-17 17:27:00.635 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>:  Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 17:27:00.635 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1000
09-17 17:27:00.637 24923-24923/<MY APPLICATON ID> D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x80659aa0>
...
```

(and this goes on and on and on and on)

The only values written are 0 and 1000, no "gray area" in the middle.

My app behaves just fine, though, with newer APIs (22, 23, 24, 25):

```
09-17 11:41:09.663 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 11:41:09.672 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 11:41:09.690 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 11:41:09.700 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 11:41:09.717 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 0
09-17 11:41:09.734 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 1
09-17 11:41:09.750 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 2
09-17 11:41:09.769 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 3
09-17 11:41:09.792 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 5
09-17 11:41:09.822 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 8
09-17 11:41:09.840 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 10
09-17 11:41:09.874 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 15
09-17 11:41:09.897 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 18
09-17 11:41:09.922 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 24
09-17 11:41:09.945 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 27
09-17 11:41:09.970 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 35
09-17 11:41:09.991 4534-4534/<MY APPLICATION ID> D/<MY ACTIVITY>: Animation Progress Value: 38
...
```

The exact same thing happens with another ValueAnimator animation (ofAlpha()) of a Drawable: not working on API 19, working fine on the other ones.

Why does this happen?

Comment: most likely you have animation disabled in "developers options"

Comment: Oh man, I'm so embarassed right now. Yes, I had the entry "Animator duration scale -> Off".
Make your comment an answer!